# Recommended tags inside iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I'm using iframe form inside html page. Which tags are necessary or recommended to use inside iframe. Should I think of it as separate html page or rather as individual element? Do I have to use html, head and body tags again inside iframe or is form enough? It seems to work either way. I just want to know how it should be done.

Comment: What's inside `iframe` should be considered as completely a seperate page. For example can you reach `css` rules or call `js` functions defined in parent page from the page you put inside iframe? NO. So the page needs to have all kinda stuff a seperate page needs.

Comment: If you have access to the iframe code, why are you using an iframe?

Comment: different domain and system, just want to clarify how to use iframe right.